# How are small data types packed in C#

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, mono

I am not looking to improve performance or memory usage, this question was purely sparked from curiosity.

**Main Question**
Given the following class will the C# compiler (Mono + .NET) pack the two `short` variables into 4 bytes or will they consume 8 bytes (with alignment)?

```
public class SomeClass {
    short a;
    short b;
}
```

**Secondary Question**
If the answer to the above question was not 4 bytes, would the following alternative offer any advantages (where `SomeClass` is used in very large quantities):

```
// Warning, my bit math might not be entirely accurate!
public class SomeClass {
    private int _ab;

    public short a {
        get { return _ab & 0x00ff; }
        set { _ab |= value & 0x00ff;
    }
    public short b {
        get { return _ab >> 8; }
        set { _ab |= value << 8; }
    }
}
```

Comment: The C# compiler won't have anything to do with it - it'll be the runtime.

Comment: When you say "is used in very large quantities" - how many are we talking about, and how are they being used?  Are you making an array/list/etc of these?

Comment: @ReedCopsey Yes, the theory of this context would be a large list with frequent access to specific entries by index.

Comment: @LeaHayes Then you should definitely at least consider using a struct.   On a semi-related note, this is worth reading: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2006/08/31/733887.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends on the runtime, not the compiler.  You can override the default behavior with [`[StructLayout]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.aspx), which can help - though the default behavior should be fine.

That being said, if minimzing total size is an absolute requirement, you may want to consider a `struct` instead of a `class`.  When using a class, each instance of the class is going to add significant overhead.  Between the syncblk, TypeHandle, etc, as well as the reference (which on a 64bit system is another 8 bytes) object instance uses a fair amount of "extra" memory above and beyond your two shorts.  For details, see ["How the CLR Creates Runtime Objects"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx).

Storing your data packed into a collection of value types can avoid this entirely, and keep the instances down to 8 bytes each total (plus the collection overhead).  Of couse, this changes the semantics in terms of usage, but if you're only using two shorts, this will reduce the amount of overhead involved in your type, especially on 64bit systems.

Comment: Thanks guys, there are some fantastic answers here. Thanks for the link, I will have a read through!

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the runtime, as @David_M says, but you can force it by using the `[StructLayout]` attribute which has a `Pack` member which you can use to control packing. Alternatively you can use `[FieldOffset]` to manually lay out a struct's members (even overlap, which is how you implement unions in .NET).

Answer (score 2):

The actual layout depends on runtime as others have commented mainly because you could run the same code across multiple platforms.

And yes in case of many objects that's save space. What you're looking for is LayoutKind (StructLayout attribute). It lets you pack members as you like. For example with Sequential it'll make sure it's packed tight.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class SomeClass {
    short a;
    short b;
}
```

For more info check out [MSDN- Structlayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)